# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that access a database frequently for a number of functions. It was running fine for several days. I received a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` exception this morning. The application wasn't doing anything out of the regular when this happened. Any Ideas on what caused this or how to prevent it in the future?

**Windows Event Log**

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
   Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. 
   [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 
Cannot open database ""MyDB"" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at ***.SubmitContextChanges(DataContext dataContext, Int32 counter) in c:\Work\***.cs:line 332
```

**Windows event right after**

```
Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. 
 This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Comment: Does the database MyDB exists? Is it online? What is your connection string?

Comment: did your dba change anything?

Comment: @SebastianMeine The database was online and being used prior to the error, and my connection string is 'connectionString="Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;database=MyDB">'

DanielA.White: There was no changed to the database.

Everything work fine after a restart aswll

Comment: Is it still online? Can you currently connect to the database using management studio?

Comment: @SebastianMeine Yes in both cases

Comment: could you change the app to not run as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`? That is not necessarily a security best practice anyway and it makes troubleshooting harder, as you cannot really try to connect to your db as that user.

Comment: May I ask why the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that one of our tables was getting too large and not flushed often enough. That the wright to database method was timing out and our retry method threw the error.

Comment: Underlying issue was bad table design causing the wright to time out.

Answer (score 4):

This message means that it did contact the server, but could not open the database specified in the connection string (named in the exception message).

Things to check:

1. That the database exists on the SQL server and that it is online.
2. That the user has access to the specified database.
3. That the default database for the login is correct and that the user has access to it.
4. That the connection string hasn't been altered.

Comment: Everything was running properly up to the error. My application uses the db several times a minute and was running for several hours earlier this morning. 

This error happened _Out of the Blue_

Answer (score 1):

`xpstar.dll` did not load out of the blue. This dll hosts the extended stored procedures used by the management tools. The fact that it loaded when the incident occurred means that there was management tool activity on the server. Which leaves open many avenues on how somebody might have messed up your database, even momentarily.

Next step is to check the [administrative default trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx) and see if you can find any activity around the time of the incident.